# How can write a code that will schedule work in weeks instead of seconds( four weeks, eleven weeks and twelve weeks) using python

Tags: python

```
import schedule
import time 
def job1():
    print ("Four weeks count")
def job2():
    print ("Six weeks")

def job3():
    print ("Eleven weeks")

def job4():
    print ("Twelve weeks")

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job1) 
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job2)
schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job3)
schedule.every(4).seconds.do(job4)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

#

How can write a code that will schedule work in weeks instead of seconds. I also want to know the date for which four weeks will happen on which date. see below.

from datetime import timedelta
print ("Four weeks rooting:" + str(datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=4)))
print ("Move plants to hardning area:" + str(datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=6)))
print ("G camp:" + str(datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=11)))
print ("PQI:" + str(datetime.now() + timedelta(weeks=12)))
Four weeks rooting:2020-04-28 14:05:02.033788
Move plants to hardning area:2020-05-12 14:05:02.033788
G camp:2020-06-16 14:05:02.033788
PQI:2020-06-23 14:05:02.033788

Answer (score 0):

```
s = schedule.every(4).weeks.do(job1)
print(s.next_run) #datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 12, 19, 11, 619804)
```

Should work according to the [documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#classes)